# Crafting a regex in Python that matches variations on a word

Tags: python, regex

"HELP", "help", "HeLp", "H!E!L!P!", "H-E-L-P", "HHHEEEEEEEEELLP" should all return matches. But they can't have any other letters interspersed between them, e.g. "hello pie" should not result in a match.

The closest I was able to come was as follows:

```
re.search("[Hh]+.*?[Ee]+.*?[Ll]+.*?[Pp]", string)
```

But that is too liberal as it allows for letters other than those in the word "help" to appear. If I just uses "+" between each bracket, it is too restrictive as that foes not allow for variations such as "h!e!l!p!" or "H-E-L-P" to be matched. I'm guessing I need to use "[^A-ZA-z] in there somewhere, but not sure where to place it or if that solution is even on the right track. -- My apologies for not including more information in the initial question. Thanks.

Comment: What does your current RegEx look like?

Comment: The closest I was able to come was as follows: re.search("[Hh]+.*?[Ee]+.*?[Ll]+.*?[Pp]", string). But that is too liberal as it allows for letters other than those in the word "help" to appear. If I just uses "+" between each bracket, it is too restrictive as that foes not allow for variations such as "h!e!l!p!" or "H-E-L-P" to be matched. I'm guessing I need to use "[^A-ZA-z] in there somewhere, but not sure where to place it or if that solution is even on the right track. -- My apologies for not including more information in the initial question. Thanks.

Comment: What about `"H-E--E-EL*LP"` (repeated letters + non-letter characters)? And how the word *"help"* (whatever he looks) has to be separated from the rest of the string: with spaces, word-boundaries, something else?

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not cover all eventualities but you can try this:

```py
^[hH]+[^\s\w]*[eE]+[^\s\w]*[lL]+[^\s\w]*[pP]+[^\s\w]*$
```

This will capture things like H1E2L3P for example, if you want to change that you will need to alter the regex

Comment: I was thinking of maybe `r'h+[^\s\w]*e+[^\s\w]*l+[^\s\w]*p+[^\s\w]*'` (with `re.fullmatch` and `re.IGNORECASE`) but yes, the question is pretty poorly defined.

Comment: You cannot "cover all eventualities" because there are an infinite number of them…

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, obviously you can cover all eventualities or else you will have a regex which misses cases it shouldn't

Comment: The solution suggested here appears to have worked. What do you mean that not all eventualities are covered? Is it that you foresee things that you think should be matched not being matched? Like what, specifically?